# Python typing: typed dictionary or defaultdict extending classes

Tags: python, types, type-hinting

I have an old piece of python code that parses a rigorously formatted text file (storing strings for localisation). Because the structure is hierarchical and some elements may or may not be present, the programme uses nested `defaultdict`s to represent it. Something like:

```
terms = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(str)) # dict<key, dict<lang, translation>>
```

Because these dictionaries are not typed (as in their members can be any type) and because they are nested, and because I need to add another level to that hierarchy, I decided to add typing to this programme:

```
from typing import Tuple, Dict, Set, List, NewType

Key = NewType('Key', str)
Lang = NewType('Lang', str)
Translation = NewType('Translation', str)
PLIndex = NewType('PLIndex', int)
```

However, I can't for the life of me figure out how to rewrite the `terms =` line above to make those nested `defaultdict`s typed.

What I ended up doing is just basically wrapping `dict` into my types, which doesn't look too good:

```
class Forms:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dct: Dict[PLIndex, Translation] = {}

    def __getitem__(self, item: PLIndex) -> Translation:
        return self.dct[item]

    def __setitem__(self, key: PLIndex, value: Translation) -> None:
        self.dct[key] = value


class Translations:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dct: Dict[Lang, Forms] = {}

    def __getitem__(self, item: Lang) -> Forms:
        if item not in self.dct:
            self.dct[item] = Forms()
        return self.dct[item]

    def __setitem__(self, key: Lang, value: Forms) -> None:
        self.dct[key] = value

    def items(self):
        return self.dct.items()


class Terms:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dct: Dict[Key, Translations] = {}

    def __getitem__(self, item: Key) -> Translations:
        if item not in self.dct:
            self.dct[item] = Translations()
        return self.dct[item]

    def __setitem__(self, key: Key, value: Translations) -> None:
        self.dct[key] = value

    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.dct)

    def items(self):
        return self.dct.items()

...

terms = Terms()
```

Is there a way I could declare my `Forms`, `Translations` and other types as just `NewType`s for `dict`/`defaultdict` and be able to rewrite the `terms =` in a way that would enforce correct types for the nested dictionaries? Or could I extend `dict`/`defaultdict` (instead of wrapping them) and be able to enforce correct types? Or is there a better way altogether?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Wrapping dicts seems to me pointless code (since it does not add any new functionality but you still have to maintain it) and I would avoid it if possible.

Now, the following is working for me:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from typing import Tuple, Dict, DefaultDict, Set, List, NewType

Key = NewType('Key', str)
Lang = NewType('Lang', str)
Translation = NewType('Translation', str)
PLIndex = NewType('PLIndex', int)

FormsDict = DefaultDict[PLIndex, Translation]
TranslationsDict = DefaultDict[Lang, FormsDict]
TermsDict = DefaultDict[Key, TranslationsDict]

terms: TermsDict = defaultdict(         # TermsDict
    lambda: defaultdict(                # TranslationsDict
        lambda: defaultdict(            # FormsDict
            lambda: Translation("")     # Default value "" (as Translation)
        )
    )
)
```

I have tested this with `mypy --strict` and it passes validation. Using this with `defaultdict` and still passing validation, it seems that you will need `cast`

```
from typing import cast

terms[Key("key1")].update(
    cast(TranslationsDict, {
        Lang("en_GB.UTF-8"): cast(FormsDict, {
            PLIndex(100): Translation("key1")
        })
    })
)

print(terms)
```

Output:

```
defaultdict(<function <lambda> at 0x107d31cb0>, {
    'key1': defaultdict(<function <lambda>.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x107d31d40>, {
        'en_GB.UTF-8': {100: 'key1'}})})
```