# Type hints for nested defaultdict

Tags: python, mypy, python-typing, defaultdict

What is the right way to write type hints for `defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(set))`?

I use Python 3.10.5 and mypy 0.971, and find mypy returns an error because `var = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(set))` doesn't have a type hint.

**Premises**

- All keys of the first defaultdict and the second defaultdict are `str`.
- Values of the first defaultdict are defaultdict. Values of the second defaultdict are `set`. (This may be obvious.)

**Sample code**

```
from collections import defaultdict
var = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(set))
```

**Output**

```
test.py:2: error: Need type annotation for "var"
```

Comment: Do you know the type of keys and values?

Comment: in pycharm, currently when I hover over it looks as inferred type is `defaultdict[Any, defaultdict[Any, set]]`. So I think you just need to fill in the `Any` values.

Comment: @funnydman Hi sorry I added the info

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python typing: typed dictionary or defaultdict extending classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59518521/python-typing-typed-dictionary-or-defaultdict-extending-classes)

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.DefaultDict I now understand `DefaultDict` is deprecated, so the question may be duplicated, but the answer should be different. @funnydman

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Starting from **Python 3.9** you can use `defaultdict` and `set` itself as annotations:

```
var: defaultdict[str, defaultdict[str, set]] = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(set))
```

For earlier Python versions there's a special [`DefaultDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.DefaultDict) type from typing module:

```
from collections import defaultdict
from typing import DefaultDict, Set

var: DefaultDict[str, DefaultDict[str, Set]] = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(set))
```